# Is it efficient to add many LinearLayouts in a parent LinearLayout which itself has a scrollView Parent

Tags: android, runtime, android-linearlayout

I have this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    setContentView(R.layout.sale_purchase_vouch);
    LayoutInflater i=getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout v=((LinearLayout)i.inflate(R.layout.row,container));
    date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Date);
    done=false;
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
    save.setText("Confirm Purchase");
```

I intend to use a button to add more linearLayouts.

XML container file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="40sp" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/Partyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="PARTY NAME" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.71"
        />
   </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/container"
                 android:orientation="vertical">


   </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Row XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter item" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/quant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Quantity"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:hint="Rate"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I am trying to run this code. Accordingly, a single row should appear but the app crashes at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is crashing because you need to switch these two lines around

```
LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
setContentView(R.layout.sale_purchase_vouch);
```

Your `container` will be `null` if you try to initialize it before inflating the `layout` with `setContentView()`. You can't initialize any `View`s until you have inflated your `layout`.

As to whether or not it is efficient is hard to say without knowing more about it but normally putting `LinearLayout`s inside of a parent `LinearLayout` should be fine. There may be a more efficient way but, as I said, without knowing more of the circumstances is hard to say. Having the `ScrollView` as a parent shouldn't be a problem as long as it only has one direct child, which it sounds like it will.

Bottomline, it sounds like you will be fine and if you don't notice any problems then it is fine.

Comment: Also, the child linearLayout has 3 editTexts. I want to get the text entered by the user from these EditText.

Comment: I am saying that how do i get the text from the user. I have tried inflating the EditTexts individually but the app crashes. Can you help me??

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize it was a question. I can help you but not without relevant code. I have no idea what/how you are trying to get it. Also, when you get a crash it is always more helpful if you post the logcat. Some, like this, was easy to spot but not all crashes are that easy to see without logcat.

Comment: The problem is I messed up the code I was trying before. Now I am doing it again but it'll take some time. So, would it be fine if i mail you the code with full details after say 10min. Thanks for your support.

Comment: If `Date` is in `R.layout.row` then you need to get your `EditText` with `date=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Date);`

Comment: I would rather answer on here. Get it done and if you can't figure it out then post a question with relevant code and logcat. If I help you through email then only you benefit. If I do it on here then people with similar problems can benefit, as well. But see my last comment on why you might be getting a `NPE` from your `EditText`

Comment: I have these XML layouts. The row XML has the EditTexts which i want to use. When the user gets the focus on the last editText, a new row should be created. For this i can use the onFocusChangeListener. But the problem is I am not able to get the editTexts function properly like they do when i create them in XML.

Comment: I can't tell you the problem without seeing the logcat or the entire code, which I don't want to see. But I can tell you that any `View` you try to initialize in `row.xml` should use `v.findViewById()`

Comment: The confusion comes because v will be inflated multiple times(Whenever the onFocusChangedListener is called). I am defining an array of editTexts to save every unique editText created by inflating v. By using the method you mentioned(v.findViewById), are you sure it is gonna work. Or will i have to define an array of 'v' and then inflate it everytime.

Comment: I have to be honest, I'm confused on what you are doing with it. It would be better to post a new question with all of the relevant code but try to keep it cut down a little. And explain it clearly. I don't know why you would inflate that layout every time. Just add the new `EditText` to it